# Why date formats miss matching when adding months

Tags: c#, string, datetime

When i am getting current date `28-Mar-2015` formated into `txtActDate` then adding months to it then i am not understanding why its getting in this `28-Mar-15` format.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
txtActDate.Text = dateTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
DateTime firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtActDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
firstDate = firstDate.AddMonths(0);
txtAccExp.Text = firstDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: sorry I added 0 to 12 so I copied first set of code.when adding all changing the date but year format coming only 2 digits.

Comment: Could you please clarify what part of documentation on `ToShortDateString` causes confusion for you?

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly because you're asking it to give you the date in short format:

```
txtAccExp.Text = firstDate.ToShortDateString();
```

You can get the current short format from your culture with:

```
using System.Globalization;
:
var dtfi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
Console.WriteLine(dtfi.ShortDatePattern);
```

In terms of fixing it, you could probably use the same method you used to populate the text field in the first place, so as to ensure it's the desired format:

```
txtActExp.Text = firstDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```